# Loop and output AJAX response that isn't key value

Tags: jquery, ajax

In JQuery, how to loop through AJAX response that isn't key/value pair. When output response to div, it looks like:

```
[true,false, true, true,...]
```

I cannot figure out how to access each element to check the Boolean value.

Comment: This looks like a simple array - why not use a simple loop?

Comment: Looks like an array,  check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to loop on a simple array.

You could do a simple JavaScript `for` loop like:

```
for (var i=0; i < [true, false, ...].length; i++){
  // Do stuff with i here...
}
```

If you wanted to use jQuery though, there is a method `each` (see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)) that you could use like this:

```
$.each([true, false, ...], function(index, value){
  // Do stuff with value here...
});
```